# What is this error? (And why doesn't it occur in other classes?)

Tags: c++, mingw

I'm trying to write a some container classes for implementing primary data structures in C++. The header file is here:

```
#ifndef LINKEDLIST1_H_
#define LINKEDLIST1_H_

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<class T> class LinkedList1;
template<class T> class Node;

template<class T>
class Node
{
    friend class LinkedList1<T> ;
public:
    Node<T> (const T& value)
    {
        this->Data = value;
        this->Next = NULL;
    }
    Node<T> ()
    {
        this->Data = NULL;
        this->Next = NULL;
    }
    T Data;
    Node* Next;
};

template<class T>
class LinkedList1
{
    friend class Node<T> ;
public:
    LinkedList1();
//    LinkedList1<T>();
    ~LinkedList1();
    // Operations on LinkedList
    Node<T>* First();

    int Size();
    int Count();
    bool IsEmpty();
    void Prepend(Node<T>* value); //O(1)
    void Append(Node<T>* value);
    void Append(const T& value);
    void Insert(Node<T>* location, Node<T>* value); //O(n)
    Node<T>* Pop();
    Node<T>* PopF();
    Node<T>* Remove(const Node<T>* location);
    void Inverse();
    void OInsert(Node<T>* value);
    // TODO Ordered insertion. implement this: foreach i,j in this; if i=vale: i+=vale, break; else if i<=value<=j: this.insert(j,value),break
    void print();
private:
    Node<T>* first;
    int size;
};

#endif /* LINKEDLIST1_H_ */
```

When I try to use it in another class, for example like this:

```
void IDS::craete_list()
{
    LinkedList1<int> lst1 = LinkedList1<int>::LinkedList1<int>();
}
```

this error occurs:

```
undefined reference to 'LinkedList1<int>::LinkedList1<int>()'
```

The constructor of the class is public and its header file is included. I also tried to include the .cpp file of the class, but that didn't help. I wrote other classes such SparseMatrix and DynamicArray in exactly the same way and there was no error!...

Comment: Have you provided the actual definitions of the template? Are they reachable from the place where the template is being called? (Also note that the syntax is wrong, the correct syntax for the variable definition would be: `LinkedList1<int> lst1;` --without the assignment and the incorrect explicit call to the constructor)

Comment: Generally speaking, template classes *must* go (the entire thing) into the header file as the *source* is needed to make the different instantiations.

Comment: @David Rodríguez: Ok. 'LinkedList1<int> lst1;' gives me same error. I even included definition (.cpp file) of template. but didn't help.

Comment: Is the function (constructor) defined somwhere?

Comment: @Chubsdad: Of course! I defined them in a cpp file. (in order to make order of method definition unimportant[?])

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [FAQ item 35.12 "Why can't I separate the definition of my templates class from its declaration and put it inside a .cpp file?"](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates.html#faq-35.12).

Most probably that's what you're running into.

Cheers & hth.,

Answer (score 2):

there are many remarks that can (should) be made on your code. I also assume that there is no reason to manually implement linked list instead of using STL other than homework, so an appropriate tag would be nice.

- it is not recommended to use `using namespace` in include files
- there is no reason for the forward declaration of the `class Node` as it immediately follows
- there is no need to use `Node<T>` inside the class, the regular `Node` is enough
- you don't need to use `this->` for data members
- it is better & shorter to use constructor initialization list
- bug: using `this->Data = NULL;` you implicitly require that `T` is a pointer. Just let `Data` be default constructed
- why Node declares LinkedList1 as friend, I don't see any use of it in the code you provide?

Your code may look like this:

```
#ifndef LINKEDLIST1_H_
#define LINKEDLIST1_H_

template<class T> class LinkedList1;

template<class T>
class Node
{
    friend class LinkedList1<T> ;
public:
    Node (const T& value): Data(value), Next(NULL) {}
    Node (): Next(NULL) {}
    T Data;
    Node* Next;
};
```

Comment: Yes it's homework :) I'll change my code. but are you sure there is no need to use using namespace? when it's removed from the header file, cout becomes undefined. cheers.

Comment: @Sorush: yes, you need to fully qualify it as in `std::cout`. The reason for this is that if anybody uses your code (as a library) and includes your file, she "inherits" this namespace from you. This is of course just a recommendation for a good practice - use `using namespace` in your private .cpp files but not in includes

Answer (score 0):

To create the object, do like this :

```
void IDS::craete_list()
{
    LinkedList1<int> lst1;
}
```

As for linker problems, if you define your template class in the source (cpp) file, you need to include it, instead of the header file.

Comment: with this syntax same error occurs. I included both of them, only header and only cpp. but in each case same error occurs again.